# Is there a workaround to change the plot.svm hardcoded title?

Tags: r, libsvm

Consider the following code. I am trying to pass the parameter `main` to change the plot title to "FooBar", but it seems to be hardcoded to "SVM Classification Plot". 
I also tried to use the function call `title` but that has the effect of overlaying the two titles, which is even more undesirable. Is there any workaround for this?

```
library(e1071)



pdf("Play.pdf")
# Generate data
set.seed(1)
x=matrix(rnorm(200*2),ncol=2)
x[1:100,]=x[1:100,]+2
x[101:150,]=x[101:150,]-2
y=c(rep(1,150),rep(2,50))
dat=data.frame(x=x,y=as.factor(y))

train=sample(200,100)

svmfit=svm(y~.,data=dat[train,],kernel="radial", cost=1, gamma=1)
plot(svmfit,dat[train,], main="FooBar")

dev.off()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main title is hardcoded, so you need to modify the code of the function.

To avoid messing with the package I would suggest creating a copy of the function in the global environment and use that.

For instance:

```
myplotSVM <- e1071:::plot.svm
environment(myplotSVM)  <- .GlobalEnv
fix(myplotSVM)
```

Then change the function definition as:

```
function (x, data, formula = NULL, fill = TRUE, grid = 50, slice = list(), 
  symbolPalette = palette(), svSymbol = "x", dataSymbol = "o", 
  main="SVN classification plot", ...)
```

and then, on line 56

```
plot.title = title(main = main, # <----- change this part!!! 
                xlab = names(lis)[2], ylab = names(lis)[1]), 
                ...)
```

So that the title will be *SVN classification plot*, or whatever you provide as `main` parameter

You can now use it as

```
myplotSVM(svmfit,dat[train,], main="FooBar")
```

Comment: Is it possible to write the modified function definition to a file somewhere so that I can reuse it later without manually editing the code every time I need to use it?

Comment: @merlin2011: I don't know whether there is a more appropriate way to do it... but I guess you can just copy the code, paste it in a new file and then use `source(filename.R)` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm wondering whether this counts as a bug and I should actually submit a patch for it.

Comment: If you think you will want to use it regularly you could load `e1071` first and then overwrite it in `.Rprofile`.

Comment: @Dwin: how does one do that? Paste the whole function in .Rprofile?

Comment: If you have never created a .Rprofile file, then you would need to do so and then paste the edited file into OR just create a text file and rename it as .Rprofile. Needs to be in your working directory. It may become invisible depending on how you OS handles dotfiles. For examples you might do a search on SO.

Comment: @DWin: yes, I know about .Rprofile, just wondering whether there was a different way to "patch" a function rather than completely paste it in the file.

Comment: I don't know of anyway of "patching" a function in a manner that would make this process more compact. In particular there is no partial editing of an R function body. You can replace a function body with `body(fn_name) <- { a set of expressions }` but that would not seem to be any more compact.

Comment: This is an answer to a three-year-old question, but it's one I'm having too. Seriously, a graph's title is hard-coded into a function library? WTF?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I just wanted to add something to the title so here's what I did:

```
plot(smv_model, test_df, battery_power~ram)
title(main= paste("                                      ", "polynomial", sep=" "))
```

and here's the result:
[image]

Comment: Crude, brutal, simple, does the job. +1.